# Using TreeMap Key as a collection of two different types

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I am new to java. While using TreeMap i wanted to use key as a collection of two objects and also the comparator should be the combination of those two types . More clearly what i want is :

```
Comparator<int> in = (in1,in2)-> {
                                 return in1.compareTo(in2);
                                 }

Comparator<String> str = (str1,str22)-> {
                                 return str1.compareTo(str22);
                                 }
Map<int , Table > table1 = new TreeMap<int,Table>(in);
Map<String , Table > table2 = new TreeMap<str,Table>(str);
```

Is there any way i can use the key as a collection of both int and string instead of making them separate , something similar to template.

Thanks for the help..!!

Comment: You need to use the wrapper classes: `Comparator<Integer>` and `Map<Integer, Table>`.

Comment: You can make a separate class, and have `int` and `String` type as field in that class.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Make a key class out of an `int` and a `String`:

```
class Key implements Comparable<Key> {
  private final int i;
  private final String str;
  public Key(int i, String str) {...}
  public int compareTo(Key key) {...}
}

TreeMap<Key, Table> map = ...
```

Comment: `Key implements Comparable<Key>`?

Comment: "Key" is the best that can be done in the sample code. Presumably, there is some meaning to the combination of the two types and that should be the basis for the class identifier in the real code.

Comment: Map<String , Table > table2 = new TreeMap<str,Table>(Key); is this right??

Comment: @katherine: No, `Map<Key, Table> table = new TreeMap<Key, Table>()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `TreeMap<Object, Table>` and use `Integer`s (not `int`s) and `String`s as keys.  Just make sure you use a comparator that consistently sorts all integers before any string.

```
SortedMap<Object, Table> mixedKeyMap = new TreeMap<Object, Table>(
    new Comparator() {
      public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
        if (a instanceof Integer) {
          if (b instanceof Integer) {
            return ((Integer) a).compareTo((Integer) b);
          } else {
            assert b instanceof String;
            return -1;
          }
        }
        assert a instanceof String;
        if (b instanceof Integer) {
          return 1;
        }
        return ((String) a).compareTo((String) b);
      }
    });
```